# Constrained Optimization for Irregular Shapes

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

I want to optimize surface area for a fixed volume of an irregular shape. I initially tried to do constrained optimization for an elliptical cone and nothing worked (especially the part for the surface area). Then I tried a sinusoidal cuboid (picture attached) and I ran into problems again. I then used a sigmoid function as the function for solids of revolution for a bottle and had issues as well. Can someone please help me to do the constraint optimization for any of these or any other weird shaped-bottles?

Sinusoidal Cuboid Picture: https://www.google.com/search?q=wave+shaped+bottle&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=AJOqlzXayC50KKyTGF3aQOnPuqXhJrI8tw:1676728220083&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidm8Wvm5_9AhVL6qQKHQfOAwAQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1440&bih=820&dpr=2#imgrc=6liUdlOqpcOJRM